# How can I write bits to a byte?

Tags: java, byte, java-6, bitset

I currently have 16 bits I want to set to variables (2 separate bytes). I've used the BitSet object to hold my bits and while in Java 1.7 there is a toByteArray() method, I need something that works on earlier versions of Java. It doesn't need to use BitSet, but I would prefer that it does (if possible).

If someone could tell me how to write something like 01101011 to a byte, I think that would help me enough. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `byte b = 0; b |= (byte) 0b01101011; assert Integer.toHexString(b).equals("1101011");`

Comment: doesn't work on Java 1.6

Comment: Compile it using Java 7 and it will run fine on Java 6. Binary literals exist only at compile time.

Comment: Ah, cool. I'll try that. What's the assert and .equals for?

Comment: You could also try `byte b = 0; b |= Byte.parseByte("01101011", 2); assert Integer.toHexString(b).equals("1101011");`

Comment: The `assert` and `equals` are just for demonstration; you can read on assertions [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html).

Comment: Ah, thanks! Both methods were helpful. I'm not sure which one I'll use though.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15811/discussion-between-veer-and-backpackonhead)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this piece of code to do that:

```
public static byte convert(BitSet bits, int offset) {
  byte value = 0;
  for (int i = offset; (i < bits.length() && ((i + offset) < 8)) ; ++i) {
    value += bits.get(i) ? (1 << i) : 0;
  }
  return value;
}
```

So to convert two bytes you will do:

```
BitSet b = ....;
byte b1 = Helper.convert(b, 0);
byte b2 = Helper.convert(b, 8);
```